# How to debug the latest kernel using arm ds-5?

Tags: debugging, arm, kernel, ds-5

https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio/resources/tutorials/linux-symmetric-multiprocessing-kernel-debug

I'm going to debug kernel using an example. But kernel version is 3.4. How to debug the latest kernel using arm ds-5?